# Are these two definition equivalent?

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

> $f(n) = \mathcal{o}(g(n))$ if
>   for any constant $c$, there exists some constant $n_0$ such that
>   $0 \le f(n) \le cg(n), n \ge n_0 $
>
> $f(n) = \pi(g(n))$ if
>   for any constant $c$, there exists some constant $n_0$ such that
>   $0 \le f(n) < cg(n), n \ge n_0 $

Are both the above definitions equivalent? In other words is the following true:

$$f(n) = \mathcal{o}(g(n)) \leftrightarrow f(n) = \pi(g(n))$$

Comment: Of course, $\Leftarrow$ is true as $<$ implies $\leq$. But the reverse implication does not hold in general due to possible vanishing issues. E.g. $f(n)=g(n)=0$.

Comment: Also, the [usual definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) involves some absolute values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, **provided** that $g$ is a positive function. It’s clear that if $f$ is $\pi(g)$, then $f$ is $o(g)$. Conversely, if for each $c>0$ you have an $n_c$ such that $0\le f(n)\le cg(n)$ for $n\ge n_c$, then you have $0\le f(n)\le\frac{c}2g(n)<cg(n)$ for all $n\ge n_{c/2}$, say.